# Is there a (intuitive) connection between injective resolutions and $Hom( -, G)$ on a chain complex?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I understand the Idea of cohomology in the context of algebraic topology and sheaf cohomology. And I have a feeling about whats mesaured by the cohomology groups (in fact by the first).
Further I see the similarity in the construction in both cases.

Is there any way to interprete injecvtive resolution in terms of Homs of the chain complex or vice versa?
Maybe in a informal way or a very special case? In the end, I am interested in toric/projective varieties over $\mathbb{C}$

Edit:

What's $H^1(X,G)$ in the topological case for me;
for simplicity I reduce to the case of $X$ a simplicial complex:

now $H^1(X,G)$ measures, how *good* a map $\varphi$ with given values on the boundary of each cell can be liftet to a map $\bar{\varphi}$ where the value of $\bar{\varphi}$ in the cells depends only on the value on the boundary of the cell.

This dependence comes from the $\delta$-function coming from the simplicial complex.

And in the sheaf cohomology case:

Because I'm interested in the toric case, I consider sheaf cohomolgy and $\hat{\text{C}}$ech cohomology as equivalent. Even if I think that $\hat{\text{C}}$ech cohomology  is nearer to the topological setting, I prefer to look at sheaf cohomology from the point of derived functor, which is telling me about the failure of lifting global sections. I understand the technical why injective resolutions arise in this case.

I dont have a good feeling for $\hat{\text{C}}$ech cohomology, a first guess is, that given a topological space $X$ with a cover $U_i$, $\hat{\text{C}}$ech cohomology tells me, how *good* sections definded on intersections of the $U_i$ (or their fiber product) can be liftet to global sections.

Please feel free to correct me if some of my intuition is wrong.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to ask, really.

Comment: If you described what you feel is measured by the first cohomology group, it might tell people what kind of insight you're looking for. It seems like that's motivating your question.